# Orthogonal trajectories of circles with fixed points

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles

$$C_1+\lambda \,C_2=0$$

are all circles passing through intersection of

$$C_1=0,C_2=0$$

Is it possible to express orthogonal trajectories of all the $C_1+\lambda \,C_2=0 $ circles using another parameter $\mu?$

Attempts with complex algebra and bipolar coordinates have not been lucky.

EDIT 1:

I took circles in the form

$$ \dfrac{x^2+y^2 + 2 f_1 x +2g_1 y  +c_1}{x^2+y^2 + 2 f_2 x +2g_2 y  +c_2}  = -\lambda $$
by differentiating and simplifying got it into form

$$  \dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{y+k}{x+h}$$

and integrated to get straight lines

$$  (y+k) = \mu\, (x+h)$$

but  find this wrong.

Comment: One of those $C_1 + \lambda C_2$ circles is (for $\lambda = -1$) a line passing through the intersection of circles. Would that help (at least for intuition)?

Comment: The line is radical axis known, but what should come next?